# Base search is not working for Chart panel

Tags: splunk, splunk-dashboard

I have created a dashboard with the base search as shown below.

The base search is applied correctly on `single` panel but in `chart` panel the base search does not seem to work. The chart panel always shows no result found. But if I give the query directly instead of referencing to base search then the chart panel also works fine.

How do I make sure that `chart` panel uses the base search?

```
<search id="base_search_app">
    <query>index=something | table msg,timestamp</query>
    <earliest>$time.earliest$</earliest>
    <latest>$time.latest$</latest>
  </search>

 <fieldset submitButton="true" autoRun="true">
    <input type="time" token="time">
      <label>Time Picker</label>
      <default>
        <earliest>-15m</earliest>
        <latest>now</latest>
      </default>
    </input>
  </fieldset>

<row>
    <panel>
      <single>
        <title>Total created</title>
        <search base="base_search_app">
          <query>| where like(msg, "%Invoked service%") | stats count</query>
        </search>
        <option name="colorMode">block</option>
        <option name="drilldown">none</option>
        <option name="rangeColors">["0x53a051","0x0877a6","0xf8be34","0xf1813f","0x006d9c"]</option>
        <option name="underLabel">No idea when to use this</option>
        <option name="useColors">1</option>
      </single>
    </panel>
  </row>
<row>
    <panel>
      <chart>
        <title>Customer response timeline</title>
        <search base="base_search_app">
          <query>| search msg="*something*" OR msg="*somethingelse*" | timechart count</query>
        </search>
        <option name="charting.chart">line</option>
        <option name="charting.drilldown">none</option>
        <option name="height">558</option>
        <option name="refresh.display">progressbar</option>
      </chart>
    </panel>
  </row>
```

Comment: you don't start a search that utilizes a base with a `|` - the pipe is implied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `timechart` command requires the _time field, which the base search does not provide.  The fix depends on the format of the timestamp field.  If it's in epoch form then a simple `| rename timestamp as _time` in the chart panel will do; otherwise, timestamp will have to be converted into epoch form using `| eval _time = strptime(timestamp, "<format string>")`.

Comment: when I print the timestamp of the logs then it is shown as `1642948509778517482`. So what should be the format string in this case?

Comment: I found that by including `_time` in my base query the issue can be resolved. So I don't need to convert the timestamp value format

Comment: Since the timestamp field is already a number, but is nanoseconds rather than seconds, the conversion is just a matter of dividing by 1,000,000,000.